# TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "float") to list

Tags: python

I have a chunk of code that is suppose to print a word with a number.

```
import Lab4

def priceList(myList):
   for item in myList:
      result = Lab4.getGroceryList() + Lab4.getPrice(item)
print(result)
```

But when I run it python throws this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
print(priceList(myList))
File "C:/Users/Christopher/Desktop/Lab4/total.py", line 5, in priceList
result = Lab4.getGroceryList() + Lab4.getPrice(item)
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "float") to list
```

I don't know why this is being thrown the code that im calling is this

```
def getPriceList():
    global price_list;
    result = [];
    f = open("price_list.txt","r");
    for line in f:
        temp = line.split(" ");
        item = [ temp[0].strip() ];
        item = item + [ float(temp[1])];
        result = result + [ item ];
    price_list = result;
    return result;
```

The getPrice function returns the price of the item that is passed
as a parameter.  If the item isn't in the price list it returns 0.0.

```
def getPrice(item):
    if len(price_list) == 0:
        getPriceList()
    for line in price_list:
        if item == line[0]:
            return line[1];
    return 0.0;
```

Why is this failing?

Comment: Because you're trying to add a list and a float. What did you intend for it to do?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I am trying to print a list I'm calling from my computer with their corresponding prices.

Comment: Semicolons‽‽   Heresy!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add a list and a float together. Either append the float to the list like this:

```
result = Lab4.getGroceryList()
result.append(Lab4.getPrice(item))
```

Or put the float in a list before adding. Like this:

```
result = Lab4.getGroceryList() + [Lab4.getPrice(item)]
```

Also, PLEASE PLEASE never use semicolons in python!

Answer (score 1):

You did it right here:

```
result = result + [ item ];
```

although, with more experience, you'll write that as:

```
result.append(item)
```

instead.  The same kinds of things are needed here:

```
  result = Lab4.getGroceryList() + Lab4.getPrice(item)
```

If `getGroceryList()` returns a list, and `getPrice(item)` returns a float, you can't just add them.  Akin to what you did elsewhere,

```
  result = Lab4.getGroceryList() + [Lab4.getPrice(item)]
```

would work.  Well, it would work in isolation.  Your `priceList()` function has other problems too ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to first convert your float to a list first if you want to use the addition operator with lists. The addition operator is basically like the `extend` method so both operands need to be of the list type in this case.

```
result = Lab4.getGroceryList() + [Lab4.getPrice(item)]
```

Although since the price isn't a list already, it makes much more sense to just append it to your list as follows:

```
result = Lab4.getGroceryList().append(Lab4.getPrice(item))
```